# Schedule some task in Acumatica

Tags: schedule, acumatica

I have following task: execute some event with some interval. In T200 manual I found that it can be done via Processing pages. For this I need to add graph with suffix process. But what puzzles me is how to make to appear buttons Process, Process All, Schedules? Another question which I have is how to execute some action by some schedule in Acumatica? What is recommended approach?

Comment: So...that's two separate questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing that distinguishes processing graphs from other kinds of pages in Acumatica is that they have a data view of type `PXProcessing<>` or `PXProcessingJoin<>` - these, together with a processing routine defined in the graph, will make the system create the *Process*, *Process All* and *Schedule* buttons on the corresponding screen. Generally your graph will look like this:

```
public class YourProcessingGraph : PXGraph<YourProcessingGraph>
{
    //Data view that provides a list of items to process
    public PXProcessing<ARInvoice,
        Where<ARInvoice.released, Equal<boolFalse>>> DocumentsToProcess;

    public YourProcessingGraph()
    {
        DocumentsToProcess.SetProcessDelegate(DoActualProcessing);

        //You can also change button captions
        DocumentsToProcess.SetProcessCaption("Do");
        DocumentsToProcess.SetProcessAllCaption("Do For All");
    }

    public static void DoActualProcessing(List<ARInvoice> itemsToProcess)
    {
        // Do something cool here
    }
}
```

You can find a better example of how to properly define a processing graph in the T200 training that you mention as well as in the source code of Acumatica - e.g. `ARDocumentRelease` graph.

Acumatica doesn't rely on the names of the classes that you define (be it DACs or graphs) when determining what is what, so the *Process* suffix (as well as *Entry* and *Maint*) is just a matter of style/convention. (One important exception is the customization objects that come with `Cst` prefix/suffix, but these are a bit different story.)

As for executing some action periodically, for this you use the *Automation Schedules (SM205020)* - that's the screen opened when you click the *Schedule* button on any processing screen. There you can create a schedule that would launch processing on a particular processing screen. The schedules can be fine tuned to match your goals in terms of frequency of execution and even allow for some additional filtering.

Comment: What is ARDocumentList ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy-paste error - should be DocumentsToProcess. Check the updated code. My bad.