# INITIALISE SCHEDULER button not showing

Tags: acumatica

We are creating automation schedules for a processing screen, found that the processing is not working as per the schedule. The last executed on is not updating too.

When we try to initialise scheduler, the button itself is not available in that site Automation Schedules Screen.

I have enabled the 'Scheduled Processing' feature in acumatica, I am using admin ID. what else need to check?

In one of the Acumatica site the INITIALISE SCHEDULER is not showing
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370502/schedule-some-task-in-acumatica

Comment: that question is not related to my problem.